# Hosting for Ruby (and Rails) like hosting for PHP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hosting

I was wondering if there was around a hosting as those that have existed for years for PHP that would give the opportunity to publish many Ruby and Rails applications and not as Heroku that forces a single application for dyno.

In classical hosting PHP I can create a folder, upload some files in php and navigate them through links.

You can something like that on some Web hosting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't ask us to recommend hosting solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For small projects, Heroku is really the best deal. Their free tier does everything you'd need for something that's occasionally used and doesn't have a lot of scaling issues. You are restricted to one application per "dyno", per account.

For anything more demanding it's not hard to set up a hosting environment on a VPS provider. Although it takes some additional knowledge, you'll be able to set up and configure a web server using a tool like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) and manage your own instances. For $10/mo. you can have a very capable server instance that will handle way more than a $7/mo. dyno can manage. Even the $5/mo. server from a provider like [Digital Ocean](http://digitalocean.com/) is a fantastic deal.

PHP's fire and forget method of hosting is convenient, but it's actually a lot more work in the long haul compared to an efficient workflow based around Rails and Passenger.

For example, using [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) and a version control system like Git you can make changes, test locally, package up into a commit and deploy on your server within minutes. It's basically effortless once you get it working.

Comment: But with DigitalOcean 10$/month I can have a server (simil like VPS?) which manage how many Rails app?

Comment: A $10 instance has 2GB of memory which should be enough for at least 4-6 applications depending on their footprint. You may be able to fit more if your applications don't have a ton of code or load in massive amounts of data into memory to render pages.

Answer (score 0):

For small production projects, I use webfaction, it's easier to push to production than to configure a complete VPS as it's more like a managed hosting (with all the tools and documentation you need for rails) . 
I use [mina](http://nadarei.co/mina/) for deployment and Git for version control.

To complete @Tadman answer you can check OpenShift if you want a more Heroku like alternative.

When I started using Rails I was also tempted to compare and seek for a 'php-hosting' like solution. But it's just a different approach.

To answer your question more precisely, you don't drop files in a folder and navigate with links in a classic rails project. You have to understand the concept of MVC, routing ...

I suggest that you give the [rails-tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) a try, it is a good starting point for understanding the whole rails ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ruby hosting on Jelastic PaaS with automated deployment to containers and scaling, as well as pay-per-use pricing model that makes it not so pricy.

There are pre-configured Apache and NGINX containers for running Ruby application, supported different Ruby versions, built-in Ruby on Rails framework, Passenger, Puma, Unicorn, Bundler dependency manager etc.

When deploying a Ruby application, only a single context (ROOT) can be used. However, you can switch between three deployment types: deployment, production and test.

More details are described here https://jelastic.com/blog/ruby-paas-hosting/

You can start with a free trial and test how it suits your project before investing any budget. This Ruby PaaS is available on different local service providers https://jelastic.cloud/